# Compare data in same table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to compare data between two different ids in the same table.

Eg) Id 123 can have items a,b,c
Id 234 can have items x,a,b
And id 789 can have items a,b,c.

My sql should be able to say that Id 123 and Id 789 are the same based on the items column , or say that Id 123 or id 234 are different based on item column.

I guess we can do this with self join in oracle , but I am not sure how .

Correction—
Items a, b , c are in 3 different records for I’d 123 or for I’d 789.

Comment: What are the items - a single column, where the value is a string, showing items separated by comma? If so, it seems that the items aren't in any particular order. Does the order matter, or is `'a,b,c'` considered the same as `'c,a,b'`? In any case, whoever designed the data model should be fired; First Normal Form is taught in the first month in any introduction course in databases.

Comment: When I say items a,b,c I meant they were three different records of the same Id 123. It is not actually a string . 
Hope I have cleared it out.

Answer (score 0):

Setup

```sql
create table T1 (id number(10), x nvarchar2(10), y nvarchar2(10));
insert into T1 values(1, 'aaa', 'bbb');
insert into T1 values(2, 'xxx', 'xxx');
insert into T1 values(3, 'aaa', 'bbb');
insert into T1 values(4, 'ccc', 'ccc');
```

call

```sql
select a.id aid, b.id bid, 'same' status  -- all items with matching fields
from 
  (select 'fakeId123' fakeId, t.* from T1 t where id = 1) a inner join 
  (select 'fakeId123' fakeId, t.* from T1 t where id = 3) b on a.fakeId = b.fakeId
where a.x = b.x and a.y = b.y 
union all
select a.id, b.id, 'different' status -- union with all items with not matching fields
from 
  (select 'fakeId123' fakeId, t.* from T1 t where id = 2) a inner join 
  (select 'fakeId123' fakeId, t.* from T1 t where id = 4) b on a.fakeId = b.fakeId
where a.x <> b.x and a.y <> b.y
```

Result

| AID | BID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | same |
| 2 | 4 | different |

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte and join each record with all other records for comparision as follows:

```
With cte as
(Select id, listagg(item,',') within group (order by item) as items
   From your_table t
  Group by id)
Select t1.id, t2.id,
       Case when t1.items = t2.items then 'match' else 'do not match' end as res_
 From cte t1 join cte t2 on t1.id < t2.id
```

Comment: Is there any size/length limitations when we combine column values with listagg??

Answer (score 0):

| ID | t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c |
| 2 | b | c | a |
| 3 | c | b | a |
| 4 | a | c | b |
| 5 | a | b | c |

```
select t1.*
  from table t1
  join table t2
    on t1.id != t2.id 
   and t1.t1 = t2.t1
   and t1.t2 = t2.t2
   and t1.t3 = t2.t3
```

Data Output

| ID | t1 | t2 | t3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c |
| 5 | a | b | c |

It is important that the table joins itself and that the IDs are different so as not to evaluate the same record.